# How to set idle and power off timeout values for USB devices

Tags: c#, windows, usb, wmi

I would like to programatically set the timeout value before an USB device goes into idle and power off states.
I can see `SetPowerState` is something that could do the work however it says it is not implemented by WMI. How can I use `SetPowerState`?

Should I use something else to specify timeout values for device to go into sleep and then power off?